# using "?" in SVG href

Tags: php, get, svg, href

I'm having some major problems trying to get a "?" inside of hrefs that are part of my SVG scripts. I want to link to other parts of my website from inside of my SVGs, and most of my pages are dynamic that require $_GET variables to create them on the fly. SVG seems to throw a spaz every time I try to include question marks inside the href, but I need to do that in order to deliver the $_GET variables... is there another way??!

Comment: In that case close the thread by clicking on the check under the vote in your post. Thanks
And you're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try to replace it with the ascii code instead? &#63;
In the same way that you have to replace the & by &amp;

Comment: hallelujah brother, you are my saviour and bow at your knees!