# Ampersands (&) in xlink:href attributes of SVG images?

Tags: svg, query-string, urlencode, ampersand, xlink

I'm building an SVG document which contains various image tags. The *xlink:href* (source URL) attributes for the images contain query strings with ampersands. If I escape them as *%26* or the ascii encoding *&#63;* they're not valid query strings and the server won't deliver the image. I can't escape them with CDATA because they're attributes (not nodes). I've tried creating an *xlink:href* node within the image tag but that get's ignored by the SVG parser. I want to use pure SVG (not SVG within HTML) so that I can convert to a JPG later, thus scripting is out...

Any hints on how I can make the below work?

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="306" height="306" xlink:href="http://host.com/image.jpg?token=asdf&expiration=9384029&etc=etc"/>
```

*Thanks!*

Comment: Oops! The solution is to replace the ampersands with the correct ascii code #38 and Not #63 (which is a question mark '?') as I had initially tried after mis-reading this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649270/using-in-svg-href

Ascii codes: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Thanks to Stunti http://stackoverflow.com/users/54949/stunti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to replace the ampersands with the correct ascii code *#38* and **Not** *#63* (which is a question mark '?') as I had initially tried after mis-reading this question: [using "?" in SVG href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649270/using-in-svg-href)

Thanks to Stunti https://stackoverflow.com/users/54949/stunti

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 5):

In all XML applications, including SVG, the following entities [are valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax) without a custom DTD:

- `&amp;` - &
- `&gt;`  - >
- `&lt;`  - <

In your case, this should work without resorting to ugly ASCII hacks:

```
<image xlink:href="http://foo.com/bar.jpg?token=asdf&amp;exp=9384&amp;etc=etc"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, *&amp;* didn't work because the browser didn't translate them back into actual ampersands at render-time and thus, the query strings didn't work... Thanks, all the same.